# Open edX Dogwood problems

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, edx, openedx

I have installed Open edX (Dogwood) on an EC2 ubuntu 12.04 AMI and, honestly, nothing works.

I can sign up in studio, and create a course, but the process does not complete. I get a nice page telling me that the server has an error. However, the course will show up on the LMS page. But, I cannot edit the course in Studio.

If I sign out of studio, I cannot log back without an error. However, upon refreshing the page, I am logged in.

I can enable the search function and install the search app, but it doesn't show any courses and returns an error.

Can someone point me to an AMI that works with, or includes, Open edX? The Open edX documentation is worthless. Or, failing that, explain to be what I am missing when installing Open edX using the automated installation scripts from the documention.

Comment: can you post the log files?  or try this Ubuntu AMI `ami-1473b577`

Answer (score 1):

This one works ami-7de8981d (us-east). Login with ssh as the 'ubuntu' user. Studio is on port 18010 and the LMS is on port 80.